# 連接 or 連結 for people connecting sector

Tags: comparison

[image]

> 人與人連結行業

It's 連結 in the picture, but 連接 in the subtitles. Which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

連結 and 連接 are basically the same when it comes to the meaning of 'connect/ link'.

The only difference is 結 is specifically refer to as 'bonded connection' while the connection in 接 can be a firm bond or an unbonded contact.

Also, 連結 can be a noun or a verb, but 連接 is used as a verb only

> 連 - link; connect

> 結 - to tie; to bond

> 連結 = link (n); to link; to connect (v)

~

> 連 - link; connect

> 接 - connect; touch

> 連接 = too connect; to link

Example:

連接兩條電綫 can mean put two wires together to complete an electrical circuit or bond two electric wires together, while 連結兩條電綫 can only mean the two wires are bonded

Answer (score 1):

the punch line (梗) is: “人與人的連結”.

originally, mr chen (陳時中) said on 13 april, that, two covid-19 cases were “確定有**人與人的連結**”.

https://news.ltn.com.tw/news/life/breakingnews/3530402

about at 40’ of the video.

since one of the case is a rich and famous male, and another case is a female working in suspected “red light” environment; mr chen did his best to let others to guess, by playing / distorting the meaning of characters.

well, this verse is quite successful, as intended

back to your question, imo, it should be “連結”, in line with the original. changing a character is, unacceptable.

stay safe :)

Answer (score 1):

I am Chinese from mainland China. We rarely use "连结" instead we use "连接" much more in daily life. Actually you can take "连结" as people in Taiwan usually use.
I'll make it easy for you. "连接"(mainland Chinese use)="连结"(people in Taiwan use). But we may use both word both in mainland China and in Taiwan."连接""连结" both of them are right.